# Receiving UDP datagrams with gpsd

Tags: udp, gpsd

I'm in a network where NMEA datagrams with GPS data are broadcast on port 7150. Some seem to be broadcast to ports 7151 and 7152 as well. I checked that with iptraf and ncat, and the datagrams are incoming.

I test starting gpsd with `sudo gpsd -N -D 5 udp://192.168.11.205:7150`
where 192.168.11.205 is the ip of my computer in the network where I expect the datagrams. With iptraf I verified that. The datagrams have 192.168.11.255 as destination address.

However gpsd never seems to get any datagram, its output reads:

```
gpsd:WARN: __STDC_IEC_599__ is missing
gpsd:INFO: launching (Version 3.24, revision 3.24)
gpsd:INFO: starting uid 0, gid 0
gpsd:INFO: Command line: gpsd -N -D 5 udp://192.168.11.205:7150 
gpsd:IO: opening IPv4 socket
gpsd:IO: opening IPv6 socket
gpsd:INFO: listening on port gpsd
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540140,0,0) succeeded, unit 0
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540141,0,0) succeeded, unit 1
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540111,0,0) succeeded, unit 2
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540113,0,0) succeeded, unit 3
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540115,0,0) succeeded, unit 4
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540117,0,0) succeeded, unit 5
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540118,0,0) succeeded, unit 6
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540120,0,0) succeeded, unit 7
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540121,0,0) succeeded, unit 8
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540123,0,0) succeeded, unit 9
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540124,0,0) succeeded, unit 10
gpsd:PROG: NTP:SHM: shmat(1540126,0,0) succeeded, unit 11
gpsd:PROG: SHM: shmget(0x47505344, 27384, 0666) for SHM export succeeded
gpsd:PROG: SHM: shmat() for SHM export succeeded, segment 1605637
gpsd:INFO: stashing device udp://192.168.11.205:7150 at slot 0
gpsd:INFO: running with effective group ID 979
gpsd:INFO: running with effective user ID 984
gpsd:INFO: startup at 2023-02-26T22:30:29.000Z (1677450629)
gpsd:PROG: CORE: pselect: timeout
gpsd:PROG: CORE: pselect: timeout
gpsd:PROG: CORE: pselect: timeout
gpsd:PROG: CORE: pselect: timeout
```

where `nc -l -u -p 7150` yields

```
$GPZDA,223320.12,26,02,2023,,*62
$GPGGA,223320.12,2826.981064,S,07350.550674,W,2,06,1.3,-0.21,M,23.45,M,6.2,0100*68
$GPVTG,359.03,T,358.12,M,10.2,N,18.8,K,D*25
$GPHDT,352.53,T*07
$PSXN,23,0.49,-0.72,352.53,-0.76*33
```

What’s wrong either with gpsd or the datagrams?

*udpate on comment*

The packets seem to come as bc. The network provider states that as well. How do I set a broadcast flag on an interface? I set the i/f to promiscuous by running iptraf in promiscuous mode in parallel, didn't change anything. gpsd -l lists NMEA.

Comment: Are the packets sent as broadcast? Does the receiving interface have the broadcast flag set? Any improvement if you put the interface into promiscuous mode? Does `gpsd -l` state that it supports NMEA protocol? Any improvement if you build it from git (building it is a nightmare)?

Comment: @Bib I did some tests, see my question for details.